# Ansible service module returns service status as stopped when the service is actually running

Tags: cassandra, ansible, datastax-enterprise

Trying to stop a service (dse datastax enterprise) using ansible 2.7

```
   - name: Stop service dse, if started
 service:
  name: dse
  state: stopped
```

What I think ansible is saying is, I'm not doing anything because this service is already stopped. Part of the verbose output:

```
ok: [myhostname.domain.com] => {
"changed": false,
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "daemon_reload": false,
        "enabled": null,
        "force": null,
        "masked": null,
        "name": "dse",
        "no_block": false,
        "scope": null,
        "state": "stopped",
        "user": null
    }
},
"name": "dse",
"state": "stopped",
```

When I check the service on the remote host this is what I see

```
[user@remotehost ~]$ service dse status
dse is running
```

So what am I missing here?
FYI it's recommended doing a `sudo service dse stop` for this service, I don't know if lack of the `sudo` will make such a difference.

Comment: You will not be able to control system services if you're not running as `root`.  Try adding `become: true` to that task (or the play) and see if it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this is since I do not have an unrestricted sudo and I do not have the ability to execute in /bin/sh thus it is failing.

The same command works when directly run on the server, and that is because

Ansible sends Python code to be executed on the targeted servers. Since Ansible is running Python code and generally not executing system commands directly, you can't limit system commands with sudo and expect them to work with Ansible. 
More: https://gist.github.com/nanobeep/3b3d614a709086ff832a

Not sure everyone has this luxury but in my case modifying the sudoers file

from

`TheGroupNameImPartOf ALL= ALL, !SU, !SHELLS`

to

`TheGroupNameImPartOf ALL= ALL`

Did the magic!